# My script fetches few of the content among several

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, web-scraping

I've written a script to get all the reviews, reviewer names and ratings from yelp using their api. My below script can produce the three reviews, reviewer names and ratings from that api. However, I can see 44 of such reviews in that landing page where I collected their api from using chrome dev tools. How can i get all of them?

[link to the landing page](https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants/buffalo-wild-wings-university-ave)

This is my try:

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/restaurants/40225?yelp_site=")
name = res.json()['name']
for texualreviews in res.json()['yelpReviews']:
    reviewtext = texualreviews['message']
    revname = texualreviews['reviewerName']
    rating = texualreviews['rating']
    print(f'{name}\n{reviewtext}\n{revname}\n{rating}\n')
```

As I said earlier: my above script can produce three of the reviews whereas there are 44 of them. How can i grab them all?

Screenshot of those reviews (location to find them in that landing page).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yelp's own API doesn't allow for query of more than 3 reviews; for whatever reason they limit the amount of reviews you can get (the same way Google limits their API to displaying only 5 reviews). If you are scraping, scrape the Yelp page directly; the site which you are hitting is using the API to display 3 reviews (the max) with a call back directly to that locations Yelp site (where all the reviews are shown); there is sadly no native way to extract all the reviews from Yelp;

The API URL You queried off Google's Developer Tools inspector in Chrome (https://eatstreet.com/api/v2/restaurants/40225?yelp_site=) is calling on Fusion's (Yelp's API) to pull the yelpReviews array in the JSON; limited to 3 by default, even if you were to register your own Fusion app you won't be able to pull more than 3 reviews, that's a hard cap set by Yelp.

You could search for some makeshift scripts out there though, I've seen many people make attempts to create libraries for pulling review data where the API's are limited. A good example is one I wrote here: https://github.com/ilanpatao/Yelp-Reviews-API

Best,
Ilan